# How many combinations of 12 rolls of a die exists where each number is rolled at least once

Tags: combinatorics

If you roll a die 12 times, how many combinations exist where all 6 sides appear at least once. Can anyone help me figure out how to solve this problem in a succinct formula.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about a simpler question? For example, if you flip a coin 4 times, how many combinations exist where both sides appear at least once? Then try a 3 sided dice 6 times. How are you solving these simpler problems? In doing so, you may find a strategy that can be expressed in terms of some simple combinatorics notation.

Comment: "Dice" is plural, "die" is singular. :)

Answer (score 0):

Out of the 12 times, you already have 6 times of known results: each side up appears once. So you only need to care about the remaining 6 times. The question simplifies to: If you roll a die 6 times, how many combinations do you have?

Let's think about a simpler case: If you roll a die 2 times, how many combinations do you have? Answer would be: 6 x 6 - 6. There are 6 duplicated combinations when 2 rolls produce a same side, so we need to subtract the duplicated 6.

Then let's think about another simpler case: If you roll a die 3 times, how many combinations do you have? Answer would be: 6 x 6 x 6 - 6 x 6 + 6. There are 6 duplicated combinations when 2 rolls produce a same side, and the remaining roll can produce 6 results, so we need to subtract the duplicated 6 x 6. However, we over-count duplications for 6 cases when 3 rolls produce a same side, so we add back 6.

By the same counting method, the case: If you roll a die 6 times, how many combinations do you have? Answer would be: pow(6, 6) - pow(6, 5) + pow(6, 4) - pow(6, 3) + pow(6, 2) - pow(6, 1) = 39990.

In general, for N rolls, number of different combinations = sum( pow(-1, N - j) * pow(6, j) ), j = N, N-1, ..., 1.

Comment: One die, two dice. :)

Comment: I am not sure *"Out of the 12 times, you already have 6 times of known results: each side up appears once. So you only need to care about the remaining 6 times"* is correct if you are using an equally probable counting method to get probabilities

Comment: So here, if you are going to divide by $6^{12}$ to get the probability all six values are shown, I think you want the numerator to be $953029440$

Comment: @Henry This has nothing to do with probabilities. And I'm not calculating probabilities. I'm just counting the number of combinations. I'm not saying every combination comes with equal probability - in fact, they don't.

Comment: @Alexis Thanks for the grammar correction! hahaha